# How to change images from one html page to another?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So what i exactly want is that when i put my PIN variable change the picture that is on the other page, this is my code: PAGE 1

```
<html>
<title>page 1</title>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="csspage.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var number;
    var pin = "";
    function change(){
    if (pin == "1234") {
        window.open("page2.html", "_self");
    }
    if (pin="2345") {
        window.open("page2.html", "_self");
    }
<body>
<input type="password" id="password"/>
</body>
</html>
```

This works correctly but I have been trying to make the second ping to change one image from the page 2 if the pin is `"2345"`. This is the code i tried:

```
if (pin="2345") {
        window.open("page2.html", "_self");
        document.getElementById("photo").src="page2.html".setAttribute("style","display:none");
        document.getElementById("photo2").src="page2.html".setAttribute("style","display:block");
```

The intention is that if the pin is one show one picture from one person and if the pin is another change it to the other user, but the pic needs to be changed from the page 1. Any way I can do this?

## IT ISN'T POSSIBLE, BETTER IDEA PUTTING THEM IN ONE PAGE AND HIDING AND SHOWING THEM.

Thanks to RecencyEffect

Comment: @manelgarcia's suggestion is correct, but also this `document.getElementById("photo").src="page2.html".setAttribute("style","display:none");` is not correct syntax. You could remove the `src=...` part and only keep `setAttribute`. It is unclear how the pages relate to the images in your question.

Comment: Then how i get the photo from page2? they have the css in common

Comment: If the images are located in different html pages, you cannot, it's just not possible. Consider including both images on the same page, and hiding/showing them as needed.

Comment: @almartinez Well, with your broken syntax it won't work either. Sorry to say that, but your code is a complete mess.

Comment: @RecencyEffect ok thanks for the info that's what i wanted to know.

Comment: @sboesch it's just a test code that i made in 2 min, so it doesn't mattter :)

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

`if(pin === "2345") {`

Instead of:

`if (pin="2345") {`

Add triple = to make sure its equal value and type.

Comment: that's not what i wanted, that works properly, is just how to change the image of page2 from page 1 as show on the code

Comment: @almartinez Even if this is not the intended solution, please note that an `if-statement` with a single `=` always evaluates to `true` as it is not comparison but assignment!

Comment: @ThomasMoors oh yes didnt see it untill now, made a mistake there sorry.